# Backface-Visibility Not Working Properly in Firefox (Works in Safari)

Tags: css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm having a problem with the back face-visibilty property. It works how I want it to in Safari/Chrome, but for some reason it's not working correctly in Firefox.

When the box flips, I get a mirror image of the front face.

Comment: I have the exact same problem in Firefox 10.0.2!  It seems like the property applies only to the front face, but when it flips with a rotateY 180deg, the back face does not have the property applied to it anymore. Anyone have a solution to this?!

Answer (score 56):

This bug has been [acknowledged by Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1201471).

The fix is to add `transform: rotateX(0deg)` to the front and back objects.

Adding `backface-visiblity:hidden` on the container, as suggested by @yalia, makes the back unresponsive in Chrome, hence that fix should be avoided.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bfzcd7ka/3/) with the fix.

Comment: Use `transform: rotateX(0deg)` fix the same bug I had on Safari

Comment: nice transform: rotateX(0deg) worked like a charm <3

Comment: I had different behavior. Adding transform: rotateX(0deg) to both faces hid the back, but adding it to just the front worked fine for me.

Comment: I wasted 3 days for this. This worked :).

Answer (score 22):

Try putting 'backface-visibility:hidden' both on the object and its container. This is what worked for me with this bug

Comment: This issue was fixed in firefox up till v30. The latest version v31 has the same issue cropping up. The solution given worked for me as well. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately adding `backface-visiblity:hidden` on the container makes the back unresponsive in Chrome.

Comment: I have the same issue with iPhone 6, Safari.  In most cases, I don't see any reason not to apply `backface-visibility:hidden` to the body, for cascading to all elements (aside from where it is needed).

Comment: Amazingly simple. Worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: This breaks backface in Chrome and Safari (it makes it oblivious to mouse interactions)

Answer (score 7):

Add only `-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;` in the parent. This worked for me.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: Non of them works for me. But I found flipping both front and back works.
My reference is from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729943/css-backface-visibility-not-working