# Backface-visibility doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm making [this website](http://hambos22.me/test_aniva/) and i'm on a big issue between browsers. I've added some animations on the site and i had problem with elements moving when i was triggering an animation. I solved it by adding `backface-visibility:hidden;` with all the necessary browsers prefixes. On Chrome everything is ok, but on firefox didn't work. Here is what i added after searching and asking here

```
 /*perspective*/
-webkit-perspective:0;
   -moz-perspective:0;
    -ms-perspective:0;
     -o-perspective:0;
        perspective:0;
/*backface-visibility*/
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
   -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
     -o-backface-visibility:hidden;
        backface-visibility:hidden;
/*transform*/
-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
   -moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
    -ms-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
     -o-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
        transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
```

Comment: According to w3Schools firefox should support this natively (no prefix) http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_backface-visibility.asp  perhaps specifying the moz prefix is causing some conflict.

Comment: I also read that. I added the moz prefix for a possible solution. But nothing

Comment: Could you please reproduce your problem at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can easily make changes to your code? Also, [w3schools is not a reliable source](http://w3fools.com), and adding prefix should not "conflict" non-prefixed property.

Comment: It's the whole site. I don't know which part i should add in the jsfiddle

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue as per explained in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604982/backface-visibility-not-working-properly-in-firefox-works-in-safari) and in this [ticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1201471).

Here is the only workaround that worked for me:

> Adding 'transform: rotateX(0deg)' to the .front, .back rule fixes
>   this.