# CSS animation works fine for Safari and Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have tried a multitude of "fixes" to try to fix the animation and just cant figure out why behavior differs so much from chrome and safari. The only it seems like backface visibility is not being applied but the common fix of applying rotateY(0deg) to the parent doesnt fix the issue

```css
.scene {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10em;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.cube {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: spinning 12s linear infinite;
  animation: spinning 12s infinite;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: center;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinning {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spinning {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(-360deg);
  }
}

.out-side {
  display: flex;
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 10em;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.cover {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-color: blue;
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(-50deg);
  transform-origin: right;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-color: blue;
}

.in-side {
  display: flex;
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 10em;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.left {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotateY(-180deg) !important;
  transform-origin: right;
}

.right {
  transform: rotateY(-230deg) !important;
  transform-origin: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="cube">

    <div class="out-side">
      <div class="back">back</div>
      <div class="cover">cover</div>
    </div>

    <div class="in-side">
      <div class="left">
        <img style="width:100%;height:auto;" src="https://www.sciencenewsforstudents.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/100220_CG_megalodon_feat-1028x579.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <img style="width:100%;height:auto;" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRpNBYv1lZ9MxxDR0qlqYm88RLm5ymSmf03dg&usqp=CAU" />
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the expected outcome? what is the issue?

Comment: The end rendering is completely different across browsers. View the fiddle on chrome/safari then on firefox. Completely different renderings. If it's not possible to accomplish consistency that would be nice to know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Backface-visibility doesn't work on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002021/backface-visibility-doesnt-work-on-firefox)

Comment: No unfortunately it does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Backface-Visibility Not Working Properly in Firefox (Works in Safari)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604982/backface-visibility-not-working-properly-in-firefox-works-in-safari)

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your combination, i tried stripping the code to the bare minimum with few edits here and there and it works fine on both browsers https://jsfiddle.net/wLbrtfku/

Comment: @ZohirSalak You are a literal saint! thank you so much. Put it as an answer and I'll mark it as so