# CSS: backface-visibility not working?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a card flipping effect, but I can't get the `backface-visibility: hidden;` working. What am I doing wrong?

```css
    .content {
      width: 100%;
      height: 70vh;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      position: relative;
      top: 50px;
    }
    
    .card {
      margin: 10px;
      width: 300px;
      height: 450px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      left: 10%;
      background-color: green;
      transition: all 0.6s ease;
    }
    
    .card:hover {
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
    
    .front, .back {
      width: 300px;
      height: 450px;
      position: absolute;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
    
    }
```

```html
    <div class="content">
      <div class="card">
      
        <div class="front">
          <p>hello</p>
        </div>
    
        <div class="back">
          <p>goodbye</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: "[not] working" is a bit vague. Maybe you can tell us what you want to achieve and what you're actually seeing.

Comment: It's a flip effect, so I want the front of the card and the back of the card to be different. The front says "hello" the back says "goodbye". `backface-visibility: hidden;` should hide the 'goodbye' from the back of the card, whereas it's not doing anything at the moment.

Comment: What browsers are you testing it in?

Comment: When I click Run code snippet it does what I would expect (which isn't nothing). It doesn't switch from showing hello to goodbye though - you've overlaid those two elements, you've none nothing to rotate one or make either opaque.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of rotating the parent, you have to rotate the two sides individually.

```css
    .content {
      width: 100%;
      height: 70vh;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      position: relative;
      top: 50px;
    }
    
    .card {
      margin: 10px;
      width: 300px;
      height: 450px;
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      left: 10%;
    }
            
    .front,
    .back {
      width: 300px;
      height: 450px;
      position: absolute;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      transition-duration: 600ms;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .front {
      background-color: green;
      transform: none;
    }
    .back {
      background-color: red;
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }


    .card:hover .front {
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
    .card:hover .back {
      transform: none;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="content">
      <div class="card">
      
        <div class="front">
          <p>hello</p>
        </div>
    
        <div class="back">
          <p>goodbye</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip) is a good example how do flip cards...

**CSS:**

```
.content {
    perspective: 1000;
}

.content:hover .card {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.content, .front, .back {
  width: 300px;
  height: 450px;
}

.front, .back {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: green;
}


.card {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}

.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.front {
    z-index: 2;
    /* for firefox 31 */
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.content:hover .card {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/tj3eacxL/

Your original CSS is at the top. The necessary changes are:

```
.card {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    background: none; /* Apply a background colour to the whole card to cover up the faces */
}
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg); /* because the back should be flipped initially when it's in the back */
}
.front, .back {
    background-color: green;
}
```