# Rotating Panel - CSS transitions breaking in Safari and Chrome - Vender prefix not entirely effective

Tags: jquery, css, vendor-prefix

I am building a simple rotating panel using css3 transitions along with a super simple jQuery function to toggle the class that rotates the panel. I have done the best I can setting up the vender prefixes (both by hand and using automated prefix services) to make Safari and Firefox happy, but alas they are not.
In Safari the text and button disappear once the panel is rotated.
In Chrome the content appears with a delay once the panel is rotated.

Update: The solution here [Backface-Visibility Not Working Properly in Firefox (Works in Safari)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604982/backface-visibility-not-working-properly-in-firefox-works-in-safari) while similar, does not resolve the problem, nor does any other answer that I have been able to find.

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding-top: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#card {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ( 0px );
          transform: translateZ( 0px );
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .7s, margin .4s;
          transition: transform .7s, margin .4s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

#card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
          transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}

#card figure {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#card .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
          transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}

.container {
  -webkit-perspective: 2000px;
          perspective: 2000px;
  width: 320px;
  height:300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 100;
}

figure > div {
  padding: 12px;
}

.link {
  background: #dfdfdf;
  color: #006BA5;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.link:hover {
  border: none;
  background: #006BA5;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 100px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

All of my files can be found in this repo/branch: https://github.com/NickTerrafranca/Rotating-Panel/tree/cross_browser

Much thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: *to make Safari and Firefox happy,* it's not true. Firefox doesn't need vendor prefixes in this purposes. However I understand your problem. The fiddle is here (you should make it before me but you don't): http://jsfiddle.net/tt9yvq5z/

Comment: Note that this: http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/examples/card-01.html is working perfectly in firefox. You can see the current specification: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility#Browser_compatibility That's experimental and the status is **working draft**. Firefox is not guilty. But maybe there is a bug

Comment: Just so you know, you can create a newline in markdown by ending the line with 2 spaces or by using 2 new lines -- `<br>` is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Doing some research I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32421734) from a different SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9604982). What they said was to do this:</s>

```
#card figure {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
```

See if that works for you.

**UPDATE**: The problem is actually with the `background`. Having the background on `#card` covers up the back. So add this

```
//remove these styles from #card
#card figure { 
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amwill/oe0pcgjq/1/) tested in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

Comment: This is an excellent tip but unfortunately didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @NickTerrafranca okay, I found the actual problem. I will update the answer.