# How to preserve-3d using css - firefox issue

Tags: html, css, firefox, preserve

I want to be able to hide TEXT1, TEXT2, TEXT3 etc. when hovering with the mouse over either the image or text.
I have managed to do this in chrome by adding 
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

The link i am sharing with you works in chrome but not in firefox.

[Working Code Link (works in Chrome but not in Firefox)](https://jsfiddle.net/tx3uf7ch/4/)

```
 #f1_card {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     transform-style: preserve-3d;
     -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;

     /** fixes non transitive 3d from parent  and child **/
     transform-style: preserve-3d;
     transition: all 0.5s linear;
     -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
     -moz-border-radius: 200px;
     border-radius: 200px;
 }
```

Could you please help me out with this issue in Firefox?

Comment: What version of Firefox do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the following style to your css:

```
.face.front {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

Seems like this is known issue. See here [Backface-Visibility Not Working Properly in Firefox (Works in Safari)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604982/backface-visibility-not-working-properly-in-firefox-works-in-safari)

Here is fix for your example:

https://jsfiddle.net/tx3uf7ch/9/

Here is minimal code to reproduce the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/5obugjqa/4/

Here is fix for it:

https://jsfiddle.net/5obugjqa/3/

Please follow this guide when asking: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And you'll either manage to resolve the issue on your own or get the answer much faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @NaThAN You are welcome! Please accept the answer if it works.