# Transform property does not work in Firefox but does in Chrome and Safari. What to do?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, firefox, css-transforms

**Udate**

Appeal for consistency - [Mozilla bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1508490)

**Udate**

Adding

```
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
```

to one side of the card, is a temporary fix that needs to be fixed properly.

The duplicate does not affect this solution and is vague.

**Question**

Particularly the `backface-visibility` here:

```
.card__face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

I tried adding the `-moz-` prefix despite it supposedly not being needed according to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=transform):

Still it does not work.  Chrome worked without any prefix and Safari worked with `-webkit-` prefix contrary to caniuse.com.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hcuaw7p3/7/).  Clicking on the icon should make the icon rotate 180 degrees.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backface-Visibility Not Working Properly in Firefox (Works in Safari)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604982/backface-visibility-not-working-properly-in-firefox-works-in-safari)

Comment: Similar but DIFFERENT please remove the dup tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `rotateY(0deg)` to your `.card__face--front` class.

`.card__face--front {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}`

http://jsfiddle.net/3h0cgukf/

Comment: That's odd. The fiddle works fine in Chrome on my side Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) Mac OS